# MySQL select query stuck "Sending Data"

Tags: mysql

I have a fairly large SELECT query and MySQL stalls while giving me a status of "Sending Data".  I don't know what could be the problem, or how to fix any of this.  Here is the query:

```
SELECT DISTINCT
    `global`.`id` AS `global_id`,
    `core_store`.`store_id`,
    `parent`.`id` AS `filter_id`,
    `global`.`option_id`,
    COALESCE(store_option_value.value_id, global_option_value.value_id) AS `value_id`,
    COALESCE(store_option_value.value, global_option_value.value, '') AS `name`,
    `global`.`position`,
    `global`.`color`,
    `global`.`normal_image`,
    `global`.`selected_image`,
    `global`.`normal_hovered_image`,
    `global`.`selected_hovered_image`,
    `global`.`state_image` 
FROM
    `m_filter2_value` AS `global` 
    INNER JOIN
        `core_store` 
    INNER JOIN
        `eav_attribute_option` 
        ON global.option_id = eav_attribute_option.option_id 
    INNER JOIN
        `eav_attribute` 
        ON eav_attribute.attribute_id = eav_attribute_option.attribute_id 
    INNER JOIN
        `m_filter2` AS `parent_global` 
        ON eav_attribute.attribute_code = parent_global.code 
    INNER JOIN
        `m_filter2_store` AS `parent` 
        ON parent_global.id = parent.global_id 
        AND core_store.store_id = parent.store_id 
    LEFT JOIN
        `eav_attribute_option_value` AS `global_option_value` 
        ON global_option_value.option_id = eav_attribute_option.option_id 
        AND global_option_value.store_id = 0 
    LEFT JOIN
        `eav_attribute_option_value` AS `store_option_value` 
        ON store_option_value.option_id = eav_attribute_option.option_id 
        AND store_option_value.store_id = core_store.store_id 
    LEFT JOIN
        `m_filter2_value_store` AS `target` 
        ON target.global_id = global.id 
        AND target.store_id = core_store.store_id 
WHERE
    (
        core_store.store_id <> 0
    )
    AND 
    (
        global.edit_status = 0
    )
    AND 
    (
        target.id IS NULL
    )
    LIMIT 10000;
```

And here is the EXPLAIN of it:

```
+----+-------------+----------------------+--------+----------------------------------------------------------------------------------+------------------------------------------+---------+-------------------------------------------------------+---------+--------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| id | select_type | table                | type   | possible_keys                                                                    | key                                      | key_len | ref                                                   | rows    | Extra                                                                    |
+----+-------------+----------------------+--------+----------------------------------------------------------------------------------+------------------------------------------+---------+-------------------------------------------------------+---------+--------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | global               | ref    | option_id,edit_status                                                            | edit_status                              | 8       | const                                                 |     734 | Using temporary                                                          |
|  1 | SIMPLE      | eav_attribute_option | eq_ref | PRIMARY,IDX_EAV_ATTRIBUTE_OPTION_ATTRIBUTE_ID                                    | PRIMARY                                  | 4       | finish_library_emea.global.option_id                  |       1 | NULL                                                                     |
|  1 | SIMPLE      | eav_attribute        | eq_ref | PRIMARY                                                                          | PRIMARY                                  | 2       | finish_library_emea.eav_attribute_option.attribute_id |       1 | Using where                                                              |
|  1 | SIMPLE      | parent_global        | eq_ref | PRIMARY,code                                                                     | code                                     | 767     | finish_library_emea.eav_attribute.attribute_code      |       1 | Using index                                                              |
|  1 | SIMPLE      | global_option_value  | ref    | IDX_EAV_ATTRIBUTE_OPTION_VALUE_OPTION_ID,IDX_EAV_ATTRIBUTE_OPTION_VALUE_STORE_ID | IDX_EAV_ATTRIBUTE_OPTION_VALUE_OPTION_ID | 4       | finish_library_emea.global.option_id                  |       1 | Using where                                                              |
|  1 | SIMPLE      | parent               | ref    | global_id,store_id                                                               | global_id                                | 8       | finish_library_emea.parent_global.id                  |       2 | Using where                                                              |
|  1 | SIMPLE      | core_store           | eq_ref | PRIMARY                                                                          | PRIMARY                                  | 2       | finish_library_emea.parent.store_id                   |       1 | Using index                                                              |
|  1 | SIMPLE      | store_option_value   | ref    | IDX_EAV_ATTRIBUTE_OPTION_VALUE_OPTION_ID,IDX_EAV_ATTRIBUTE_OPTION_VALUE_STORE_ID | IDX_EAV_ATTRIBUTE_OPTION_VALUE_OPTION_ID | 4       | finish_library_emea.global.option_id                  |       1 | Using where                                                              |
|  1 | SIMPLE      | target               | ALL    | NULL                                                                             | NULL                                     | NULL    | NULL                                                  | 1012396 | Using where; Not exists; Distinct; Using join buffer (Block Nested Loop) |
+----+-------------+----------------------+--------+----------------------------------------------------------------------------------+------------------------------------------+---------+-------------------------------------------------------+---------+--------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

I'm not a very good db admin, so I don't know what is going on here.  When this is run from the application (Magento 1 application), this stalls out and will eventually cause a timeout in several hours.  So if anybody knows what I would need to optimize this, or get past the "Sending Data" status, it would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: From the explain plan it looks like there is a missing index on the table `m_filter2_value_store`. If you could provide the output of `SHOW CREATE TABLE m_filter2_value_store;` then it might be easier to give more exact advice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the `EXPLAIN` `target` is the worst part.  So...  See if it helps to change

```
    LEFT JOIN  `m_filter2_value_store` AS `target`  ON target.global_id = global.id
      AND  target.store_id = core_store.store_id
 WHERE ...
      AND  ( target.id IS NULL )
```

to

```
 WHERE ...
   AND NOT EXISTS( SELECT 1 FROM m_filter2_value_store
             WHERE global_id = global.id
               AND store_id = core_store.store_id )
```

EAV sucks.  See if you can improve some indexes with the tips [*here*](http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/index_cookbook_mysql#speeding_up_wp_postmeta).